# Do while loop not returning value

Tags: vba, loops

I am trying to get the code below to work. My goal is to incrementally increase the 'test' variable until the sum of it and the markup is equal to the total fee (subfee + markup = totalfee). The code below is what I have now and it is returning a '-' in my target cell.

```
Public Function DetailersFee(TotalFee As Double) As Double

Dim test As Double
Dim markup As Double

test = 0
markup = 2 * (test ^ 0.75)

Do While (test + markup) < TotalFee

    test = test + 50

    markup = 2 * (test ^ (0.75))

Loop

test = DetailersFee

End Function
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking to return the value in test at the end of the function?  Then DetailersFee = test as opposed to test = DetailersFee.

Comment: This should probably be an answer.

Comment: Your result (return) statement is backward. It should be `DetailersFee = test`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to return the value in test at the end of the function? Then replace:

```
test = DetailersFee
```

with

```
DetailersFee = test
```

You want to set the function name equal to the variable you want to return, not the other way around.